# RFECV with parallel jobs

Tags: parallel-processing, scikit-learn

I would like to perform Recursive Feature Elimination with the included cross validation (RFECV). My problem is that although I have heavily subsampled my data, with my number of features (278) the process is way too slow and would probably not be concluded in the time that I have allocated for my experiment.

I have seen that typical cross-validation in scikit-learn supports parallelization, by defining the number of jobs that can be run in parallel. Is it possible that the tasks from RFECV to be parallelized ?

Answer (score 4):

The [changelog for the version 0.18 release](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-18) shows that RFECV now supports `n_jobs`.

Following the example in the [RFECV documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) (I changed `n_samples` from **50** to **5000**)

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.svm import SVR

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=5000, n_features=5, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
```

#### 1 job : 22.5s

```py
%%time
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, n_jobs=1)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)

CPU times: user 23.1 s, sys: 2.71 s, total: 25.8 s
Wall time: 22.5 s
```

#### 4 jobs : 11.8s

```py
%%time
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, n_jobs=4)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)

CPU times: user 3.42 s, sys: 312 ms, total: 3.74 s
Wall time: 11.8 s
```